# How to implement Shopify's new ProductFilter on the latest storefront API

Tags: graphql, shopify, shopify-storefront-api

I have been trying to follow [this guide](https://shopify.dev/docs/custom-storefronts/building-with-the-storefront-api/products-collections/filter-products#step-2-combine-filters) with examples step-by-step, but when I run the following query, Shopify returns every product from the collection instead of the filtered products. I have confirmed that I have the variant options on my products, it just appears to not apply the logic. Appreciate your time

```
query shopifyCollectionQuery($handle: String!, $limit: Int!) {
  collection(handle: $handle) {
    id
    title
    handle
    products(first: $limit, filters: {variantOption: {name: "Color", value: "Diamond/Grey"}}) {
      pageInfo {
        endCursor
        hasNextPage
      }
      edges {
        node {
          title
          totalInventory
          handle
          options {
            name
            values
          }
          variants(first: 100) {
            edges {
              node {
                selectedOptions {
                  name
                  value
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't install Shopify's new Search and Discovery plugin, you only have access to the default price/availability filters. Once you install the app, you can create new filters that get exposed on the storefront API (including variant based filters)

https://apps.shopify.com/search-and-discovery